# The Judge would not allow a guilty plea at the arraignment, and put in a plea of not guilty. What comes next?

Tags: criminal-procedure, courtroom-strategy

From my research, the most likely reason is that the judge was only following procedure, when it became apparent the client did not have legal counsel.

In this case, the client is charged with misdemeanor marijuana possession, but the court has him on tape admitting to marijuana trafficking and other felony offenses. The officer chose to charge him with a misdemeanor because of his honesty and cooperation (we assume).

The client would like to self-represent, and plead guilty to the original charges of misdemeanor marijuana possession. How would the client go about finding out if these original charges still stand, or if the charges have been upgraded? Court documents don't indicate any changes in the charges filed, yet.

Would it be okay for the client to write a letter, directly to the prosecution, asking them  to clarify the charges?

The client does not wish to make things worse on himself, and only wishes to self-represent because he doesn't wish to fight the charges and doesn't believe an attorney is required for this.

Comment: How can he (you?) be a "client" without legal representation? Or do you mean to say "defendant"?

Comment: If you're having trouble following the charge sheet, that would be a sign that an attorney *is* required. There's no shame in that, that's what they're for. You (or the hypothetical defendant) should definitely get one.

Comment: The question here doesn't seem to match the description.

Comment: @Cadence and if the judge thinks that the defendant doesn't understand the charges, they can only enter a plea of "not guilty," because doing otherwise would violate due process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would the client go about finding out if these original charges
> still stand, or if the charges have been upgraded?

Call the clerk of the relevant court (or go in person to the clerk of the relevant court's office, which is a stand in line until it's your turn to talk to a deputy clerk behind a counter situation, similar to waiting in line for a bank teller) and provide the case number.

There has to be a filing with the court to upgrade the charges (sometimes delayed a few hours if the upgrade happens on the record in open court).